# How to play an opus audio with cursor (vertical line) moving along the sound wave image in IE11

Tags: javascript, multithreading, audio, internet-explorer-11, opus

IE11 doesn't support playing an opus audio file. That's why i am using **ogv.js** javascript library for playing it in IE11. This library streams audio data to internal flash player of IE11 and plays it. The problem is while playing an audio file parallel i have to redraw the entire image with cursor [(vertical line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js9FJ.png) continuously to indicate the position of the audio being played back.
Javascript is a single threaded scripting language so i cannot perform both tasks at a time.

I call functions as follows.

`var chart = new Chart();`

`var player = new OGVPlayer({});`

//in chrome and firefox i use
`var player = document.createElement('audio');`

`player.src = "test.opus";//duration of audio is 10 seconds`

`player.load();`

`redraw_chart(0, 100);`

`player.play();`

**function redraw_chart(position, time) {**

```
if(position <= time) {

    position++;

    setTimeout(function() {

       chart.redraw();

       redraw_chart(position, time);

    }, 100);
}
```

**}**

**In IE11**, above code redraws the chart after every 10th of second continuously for 10 seconds and then plays the audio file. But i want to play them parallel.

**Note:** In Chrome and firefox this code works fine because in both browsers i use audio control for playing the opus file and rest javascript redraws the chart parallel while audio control plays the audio file.

**I will be very thankful if anyone can help me out.**

Answer (score 0):

We can see that you want to perform 2 parallel tasks. Which is not possible using JS.

I suggest you to check Parallel.js

Parallel.js is a tiny library for multi-core processing in Javascript. It was created to take full advantage of the ever-maturing web-workers API. Javascript is fast, no doubt, but lacks the parallel computing capabilites of its peer languages due to its single-threaded computing model.

Parallel.js solves that problem by giving you high level access to multi-core processing using web workers. It runs on node and in your browser.

Reference:

[Parallel.js](https://parallel.js.org/)

You can also try to refer this link to get some information about web workers.

[Parallel programming in JavaScript using Web Workers](https://itnext.io/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db)

You can try to use above APIs to play the audio file and draw the chart simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thanks for your answer, but Web worker [do not have](https://itnext.io/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db) access to all the browser APIs due to its execution in different thread. It can not access DOM because DOM does not belong to its context. window and document objects are also not available. Actually i want to access DOM object (for drawing chart and playing audio file).

Comment: In that case, I suggest you convert your audio file to the supported format by IE browser. Then you can try to use anyJS audio player to play it with audio controls. I did not get any other way to play your audio file and show the graph simultaneously for IE browser.

Comment: Thanks very much.